# How to efficiently get indexes of ones in a binary string

Tags: python, python-3.x, binary

I'm looking for an efficient way of determining which bits are ones in a binary representation of an integer.

I have a library ([adafruit_mpr121](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_CircuitPython_MPR121/blob/master/adafruit_mpr121.py)) that returns an integer that is constructed along this lines:

```
a = bytearray(2)
b = bytearray(2)
((a[1] << 8) | (a[0])) & 0xFFFF
```

I can get string binary representation of said integer with format like this: `'{0:0<12b}'.format(bin_int)` and I can probably find indexes with `re.finditer()` but I would think there's some more efficient way without walking through all those operaions. This full operation takes around how long I am sleepig between device skans, so not so good at all:

```
>>> timeit.timeit('[m.start() for m in re.finditer("1", "{0:0<12b}".format(((a[1] << 8) | (a[0])) & 0xFFFF))]', setup='import re; a = bytearray(2); a[0]=16; a[1]=5', number=10000)

0.026143900002352893
```

Does anyone know of any way that would be faster?

Answer (score 2):

Operating in the realm of numbers, rather than strings may be more efficient. I found this function to be approximately 50% faster than the regex approach.

The method is to left-shift the number by its bitlength - 1 to determine whether the most significant bit (MSB) is set. If it is set, compute the index and decrement by the power of two represented by the MSB.

```py
def compute_indexes(n):
    orig_num_bits = n.bit_length() - 1
    indexes = []
    for num_bits in range(orig_num_bits, 0, -1):
        if (n >> num_bits) == 1:
            indexes.append(orig_num_bits - num_bits)
            n -= (1 << num_bits)
    return indexes
```

Comment: Someone more bitwise than I could probably find a faster way?